# Difficulty in solving the most famous online ( 8÷2(2+2) question with 2 different approaches

Tags: arithmetic

For the problem 8÷2(2+2)
I have found two approaches to solve the problem.

1st one is:
$\frac{8}{2(2+2)}$

This looks like a direct approach ad we got 1 as answer.

2nd one is using BODMAS:

8/2(2+2)
8/2(4) - Brackets
8/2 * 4 i.e 4*4 - There are no brackets for 2 and 4. Therefore , using BODMAS. Divison will have a higher precedence.
Answer comes to be 16.

Therefore , I am getting 2 answers and am not sure which one is the correct one.

Comment: As written, the "problem" is ambiguously stated. I hate these because it neglects grouping symbols, which is why no self-respecting person uses $\div$ to denote division without the presence of grouping symbols.

Comment: I mean you can just interpret it the cs way where operations of similar significance are performed left to right. As long as you *define* what you are going to do everything is good lol. This problem is ambiguous *because* it’s not properly defined.

Comment: They problem itself is wrong because it's ambiguous. It's one of the reason we don't use $\div$ in higher mathematics. Also, it's not associative meaning $(x \div y) \div z \neq x \div (y\div z)$ in general. Instead we multiply by inverses (reciprocals) since multiplication is associative.

Answer (score -2):

If we were very picky, then we could claim that division does not really exists. What we commonly call division is multiplication with an inverse element. As soon as we use a linear notation such as $\div$ or $/$ and there is more than one letter after it - in your example from the alphabet of digits and arithmetic signs - it is no longer obvious which of them should be inversed. Furthermore, "division" is no associative notation, i.e. order matters. This means that "division" requires parentheses in all linear notations.